# Intellij Idea ReferenceError: is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea

When debugging typescript code from my testcases in Intellij Idea I get the following error inside the Evaluate window (Alt + F8):

```
ReferenceError: InternalServerException is not defined
    at eval (eval at getStatusCodeAndResponse (C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Projecten\stations-api\app\common\error-handler.ts:17:13), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at Object.getStatusCodeAndResponse (C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Projecten\stations-api\app\common\error-handler.ts:17:13)
    at Lambda.handler (C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Projecten\stations-api\app\get-guiding-lines-combinations.ts:38:20)
    at Lambda.<anonymous> (C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Projecten\stations-api\node_modules\@aws-lambda-powertools\metrics\src\Metrics.ts:277:41)
    at Lambda.<anonymous> (C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Projecten\stations-api\node_modules\@aws-lambda-powertools\logger\src\Logger.ts:337:41)
    at Lambda.<anonymous> (C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Projecten\stations-api\node_modules\@aws-lambda-powertools\tracer\src\Tracer.ts:364:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Projecten\stations-api\app\get-guiding-lines-combinations.test.ts:41:41)
    at Promise.then.completed (C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Projecten\stations-api\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:391:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at callAsyncCircusFn (C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Projecten\stations-api\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:316:10)
```

The way I import my custom class:

```
import {
    BadRequestException,
    Exception,
    InternalServerException,
    NotFoundException,
} from '../models/Exceptions';
```

The custom class itself:

```
export class InternalServerException implements Error {
    message: string;
    name: string = 'InternalServer';
    statusCode: number = 500;

    constructor(message?: string) {
        this.message = message ?? 'Internal server exception';
    }

    createResponse(): APIGatewayProxyStructuredResultV2 {
        return {
            statusCode: this.statusCode,
            body: this.message,
        };
    }
}
```

While it can easely find my custom classes etc when running the tests. How can I get my classes recognized inside the evaluate window? Since this makes debugging a lot easier. (The version I am using is Intellij Idea 2022.3.2 ultimate)

Comment: Must be related to the way code is transpiled by webpack + missing name mappings in sourcemaps. What does the `InternalServerException` definition look like? Is it a module imported from the other file?

Comment: @lena I have added a code example of how I import it inside error-handler.ts and what the class itself looks like

Answer (score 0):

ReferenceError exceptions while evaluating imported modules (`InternalServerException` in your case) during debugging is caused by the weird way imported objects are transpiled + missing name mappings in sourcemaps: if the variable is renamed while transpiling/obfuscating, and no appropriate name mapping is provided, the debugger won't be able to match variable in source code with the one in VM.

For example, `import somefunction from './somefunc'` is usually compiled to

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var somefunc_1 = require("./somefunc");
somefunc_1.default();
```

and no name mappings are generated (`"names":[]` in generated sourcemap), so the debugger can't match the variable in `.ts` file with the code in runtime and shows undefined

Tickets that can be related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9627, https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3957, https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1468